# api/products/getProducts to XML

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a website in which you have a product catalog, I want to see these products on Facebook and in Google Merchant Center, and they ask me for a special URL:

Google: The URL of the file location must start with http: //, https: //, ftp: //, or sftp: //.
FaceBook: Must start with http, https, ftp, or sftp. Files can be up to 8GB in size and must be in CSV, TSV, or XML (RSS / ATOM) format.

My programmer gave me this:
https: // webpage / api / products / getProducts

and obviously when entering it in google or facebook it tells me that this is not correct. I told my programmer and he told me that I have to configure it myself !!! just doing some configuration with JSON.

Could you help me, the database is MongoDB and the platform is NodeJS

Comment: Can you share the content type of that's returned when you request your page? From your question, it seems like it needs CSV or XML but I think you are returning JSON. Looking at the content type will give you a proper indication as to what's being returned and how to use that or change that to make it work.

Comment: Hello, how are you? It is that the programmers really do not let me enter the database, but when I tell them that I need the URL to locate the products, they tell me that it can only be exported to API, this: https: // webpage / api / products / getProducts and it tells me that I have to get someone who is able to convert that URL into what I need (xml, or csv, etc) and I don't know much about this, but I feel that he is wrong, it is the only thing that he gave me.

Comment: The document on Google Merchant center is clear that the link should point to a file that is either (a tab separated text file, TSV) or an XML file. In that case, your Node.js server should add a product catalog to in the format you want (TSV or XML) and save it in an asset directory. Then you can use that link for this. This file will need to be generated each time your catalog changes (product added/removed). I also saw that you can use Google Sheet. In that case, your server can update (duplicate) the catalog on a Sheet App and you can use that as a link.

Comment: File formats: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160567#zippy=%2Ctext-spreadsheet-or-tab-delimited.  Feed submission: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/1219255?hl=en.  Here are the links for reference. I am speculating from my cursory read that both of these methods are proper integration methods but of course, you will need to develop the solution and see how feasible it is for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason, but you can use [facebook feed debugger](https://business.facebook.com/ads/product_feed/debug) and explore what's the issue, so then you can find out the actual problems.